# html amp thai charset

Tags: html, amp-html

I have a test page in amp (accelerated mobile page). It is validate as well but the Thai characters are not correctly shown.
[AMP validate Thai symbols wrong](http://www.pizzaoventhailand.com/future/index.html)

Then I have the same page were I substitute `<meta charset="utf-8">` with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in this case the Thai characters are render correctly but the page is not anymore validate:[AMP not validate Thai symbol OK](http://www.pizzaoventhailand.com/future/index2.html)

You can see the Thai language mouseover on the Thai flag (as title) and as last word in the page. How can I correctly render Thai characters in AMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you realy make a 1:1 copy from index to index2? The characters in source code are different!?
2. "contain a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag as the first child of their head tag."
   But your first tag is a style tag!

Comment: Thank you for note. In my computer are the same (index = index2) but when upload change. I don't know why. Do you have suggestion to render Thai characters using amp? Source of index: http://www.pizzaoventhailand.com/future/index_text.txt

Comment: Oh, I solved it! I copy the source in notepad and save in txt. Before saving I choose encoding UTF-8 after saved I change the extension from txt to html (rename) and upload and was correct: http://www.pizzaoventhailand.com/future/index_text.html also validate!

Comment: OK, character encoding in editor and meta charset in document head must be the same!